# Clojure Postgresql Drivers not found

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I'm at that point where frustration just makes you incapable of seeing the solution...

My `project.clj`

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]                                                                                                                                                           
               [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.4.2"]                                                                                                                                                         
               [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4.1208"]]
```

1. Run `lein deps` (all is okay)
2. Run my query:

   (db/query "postgresql://user:secret@host"
             ["select * from table limit 1"])

I get the following error:

> 1. Unhandled java.sql.SQLException
>      No suitable driver found for
>      jdbc:postgresql://host

...Please. Any ideas?

Comment: just including the libraries in your dependency doesn't configure your connection to the database. you have to specify that specifically, typically in the `:classname` value of the connection map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably need to specify the java driver to use and the other parameters in the db descriptor.

I usually use something similar to:

```
(use 'clojure.java.jdbc)

(let [db { :classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
           :subprotocol "postgresql"
           :subname "//192.168.99.100:5432/postgres"
           :user "postgres"
           :password "mysecretpassword"}]
       (query db ["select count(*) from example" ]) )

 ; ({:count 6005247})
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your db spec is wrong, I use postgresql spec:

```
postgres://user:password@host:5432/mydb
```